# How do I show <br /> from a database in a textarea as HTML rather than text?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I need to know how to echo a line break from my database in a textarea as html rather than text.

Comment: use a br or use \r\n like you said and do a find/replace before spitting out the data.

Comment: You could use the nl2br function?? i.e echo nl2br($row['text']); http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Neither of these solutions work.

Comment: Are you storing HTML as text in you DB and then want to display it as HTML? if so you could try echo htmlspecialchars($row['text']); ??

Comment: I think it's reverse - he stores <br />, but doesn't want the user to see this, but instead see the actual linebreak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hye this works for me!!! I think this may help you..

my table has two columns 'a' and 'c';
values are 'aa' and `<input type="text">`

My code:

```
    <?php
    $host='localhost' ; 
        $mysql_db="db2" ; 
        $mysql_u="root" ; 
        $mysql_p="" ; 
        $con=mysqli_connect( "$host", "$mysql_u", "$mysql_p","$mysql_db");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

        else
        {
        $c="select c from site where a='aa'";
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$c);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $a=$row['c'];
echo "<textarea>$a</textarea>";
                        }
        }
                        ?>
```

This outputs a text box in browser... :)
Like this you can store '`<br>`' in table for col 'c' it outputs a new line...

for ur question this is the exact answer...
use the code edited above... but change in db

for ex here, in column 'c' change entry as `stmt1 &#13;&#10; stmt2 &#13;&#10; stmt3`

you will get these three stmts in three lines(like 
 in html)

`&#10;` - Line Feed and `&#13;` Carriage Return are HTML entities

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already tried that. When my code pulls <br /> from my database it literally echoes it in the textarea rather that echoing it as HTML.

Comment: @DF340 edited my answer i think this was what exactly u need... if u got output accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a function that converts linebreaks to new lines and run that. That's presuming I understood you correctly and you want to return 
 into linebreaks.

```
function br2nl($content)
{
    $content = str_ireplace("<br /> ", "\n", $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Simply use this function on whatever content you wish to revert back.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use htmlentities($yourString). This will convert 
 into new line. For reference:
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: This is doing the opposite of what I want to do.